# git mimic old commit from other repository

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rewrite-history

## Why

At our company we started using some open source code and started patching it. I now want to make these changes public, so I want to apply these changes with the correct authors and author dates (I don't want to take credit for the work I didn't do).

### Question

- in `company-repo`, I  have commit `123456789` which I want to mimic
- in `new-repo`, I prepared a commit (using `git add -p`).

Now I want to create a commit which mimics commit `123456789` from `company-repo`, but create this commit inside `new-repo`.

### ideas

- `git commit -C` can take the git commit message from another commit, but this fails (`could not lookup commit`)
- since this is across two different repositories maybe creating a patch? But since filenames have changed that will be complicated
- just parsing the information needed and reusing? What should be copied? Timestamps, commit message, others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easier way to do this, but I would parse the **author**, **message** and **timestamp** and reuse those when committing.

Set these two variables correctly:

```
OLDREPO=/path/to/company-repo
HASH=123456789 # hash of commit to mimic
```

then you can extract the values from the old commit:

```
DATE=$(git --git-dir=$OLDREPO/.git/ show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%cd' $HASH)
AUTHOR=$(git --git-dir=$OLDREPO/.git/ show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%an <%ae>' $HASH)
MESSAGE="$(git --git-dir=$OLDREPO/.git/ show --no-patch --no-notes --pretty='%B' $HASH)"
```

and use them for your new commit:

```
git commit --author="$AUTHOR" --date="$DATE" -m "$MESSAGE"
```

**NOTE:** I did not set `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` on purpose. Technically the commit is created today, while the author wrote his code a long time ago.

Comment: That's pretty much the way to go. It's up to you whether to set the committer information too. If you want to set all six items (name, email, timestamp X author, committer), there are the six env variables if you want to go for symmetry. `--author` sets two of the six. `--date` sets one, so you can use that instead of `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` if you like.

Comment: What six items are you talking about? I see GIT_COMMITTER_DATE, GIT_AUTHOR_DATE, probably two more to set the identity for author and committer? What more?

Comment: thanks for the tip on `--date`, that would indeed be more symmetric.

Comment: The six environment variables are `GIT_{AUTHOR,COMMITER}_{NAME,EMAIL,DATE}`.